# Error sending Office 365 email mail using php

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

I want to send mail as outlook mail... but it shows the connection error and authentication error if some port numbers are changed... what wrong in my code....

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host       = "outlook.office365.com";
$mail->Port       = 993;
$mail->Username = "harish.reddy@skoopview.com";   
$mail->Password = "XXXXXXX";
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName= $FromName;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->addAddress('harish.reddy@skoopview.com','harish');
if(!$mail->send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "E-Mail has been sent";
}
```

It shows error like this ... What i do ??

> SERVER -> CLIENT: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
>   [SABLAE4AUABSADAANgBDAEEAMAAwADUAMwAuAGEAcABjAHAAcgBkADAANgAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
>   * BYE Connection is closed. 13 2016-09-12 10:50:13    SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 2016-09-12 10:50:13 SMTP Error:
>   Could not authenticate. 2016-09-12 10:50:13   SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer
>   Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Thankyou....,

Comment: So it works if you leave the port numbers unchanged? Great. Leave them unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

As George stated, the port should be 587. Make sure you are using TLS:

```
$mail->Port = 587;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com;smtp.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
```

But Outlook self-signs its own SSL/TLS certificate. Hence you need to add this piece of code as per https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/914:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try port 587 for SMTP - more details here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

Comment: if i change port number it shows like this                                               2016-09-12 10:55:20 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-09-12 10:55:20 SMTP connect() failed.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed ... please can you share your code ..

Comment: Is it possible to send outlook mail using phpMailer ..? please share the sample code if u got success message ...! and is there any settings to change in godaddy for send outlook mail...